# Апостроф при сокращениях

Tags: словообразование, сокращения, апостроф

Встречались такие конструкции: "Спок'нок" в переводе иностранной литературы. Возможно такое употребление со скидкой на то, что это художественное произведение? Или переводчику надо было передать краткую форму как-то иначе?
Пример не единственный, но запомнился этот.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95379/discussion-on-question-by-----).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это передача особенностей произношения. Апострофом можно показать не просто сокращение, а, например, запинки в словах.